# Should the RenderFarm chat room be promoted more prominently?

Tags: discussion

Should the RenderFarm chat room be promoted more prominently on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ so that more people will know it exists?

Currently, we have lots of notices about rooms not blender related, but none about the Renderfarm:

[image]

I only found out about Renderfarm by accident somehow.

If we want more participation, I think we need to promote it more prominently.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think we need to promote the chat feature of the Blender Stack Exchange site for the following reasons:

1. I think it is safe to assume that most user come here to ask and answers questions, not to chat
2. The chat feature is not even that hard to find

   [image]
3. An active user will discover this on their own
4. The chat is not the main goal of the site